# Check what values doesn't exist in SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about MySQL table.
I have 2 tables (users (user_id and other rows) and answers (id, answer_id and user_id))

I would like to check, which questions the user hasn't answered (for example, in answers table exists 5 rows - 4,6,8,1,3 (but questions are 10), I would like to get out from database values 2,5,7,9,10).

How to write a query like this?
I've tried with JOIN, but nothing was successful at all!

Comment: Do you also have a questions table? Or any other table that `answer_id` relates to?

Comment: Could you demonstrate your tables more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use LEFT JOIN, it's faster.

```
SELECT q.id
  FROM question q
  LEFT JOIN answers a
    ON a.question_id = q.id
  WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Not necessarily in all situations, but as a rule of thumb, this is indeed likely to be faster than using a subquery.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have a questions and an answers table, this is the standard TSQL solution:

```
SELECT Q.QUESTION_ID 
FROM   QUESTIONS Q LEFT JOIN ANSWERS A ON Q.QUESTION_ID = A.QUESTION_ID 
WHERE  A.QUESTION_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I can confirm that this will work in MySQL; you were faster than me at providing the answer.

Comment: I am not sure it is the *"standard SQL Solution"*, It is a solution certainly, but I would never use this in SQL Server for example because it is slower than `NOT EXISTS`. All things being equal though, it is then personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you've got a `QUESTION` table:

```
select *
from question
where not exists(
    select 'x'
    from answer
    where answer.question_id = question.id
)
```

If you haven't got a `QUESTION` table, IMHO there's no solution

Comment: Not with an INNER JOIN, but there's also LEFT|RIGHT JOIN which solves this.

Comment: @Piskvor: Dear, I used NOT EXISTS not INNER JOIN. Right your second part, is the same thing of LEFT/OUTER JOIN with check on NULL value of the other table in WHERE clause

Comment: I am aware what you used; I was replying to "there's no [other] solution". As you can see in the other answers, there apparently _is_ one.

Comment: @Piskvor: My sentence: "there's no solution" was referred on existing of QUESTION table ;). I've edit my answer for better reading

Comment: Oh, all right - I have misunderstood you then; I apologize :)

Comment: @Piskvor: Don't worry. I've edited my answer on base on your comment ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

not sitting in front of a mySQL DB but it should be something to the point of (you didn't tell us where your questions are listed so I put in a placeholder) It also seems like your answer table HAS to have or should have a link to the question_id it is answering. If I made any incorrect assumptions please let me know and I will edit as needed.

```
Select question_id from question_table 
where question_id not in (select question_id from answers)
```